# Javascript to scroll <textarea> content back to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the following code, changed so that on button press, it scrolls the text area content from bottom to top.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $textarea = $('#update');
    $textarea.scrollTop($textarea[0].scrollHeight);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Scroll</button>
<textarea Name="update" Id="update" cols="50" rows="25"></textarea>
```

Comment: [Scroll to top of jQuery-Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673159/scroll-to-top-of-jquery-textarea) | Just change `$textarea.scrollTop($textarea[0].scrollHeight);` => `$textarea.scrollTop(0);`

Comment: Do not put `document.ready` inside a `click` function!

Answer (score 12):

Change the following line `$textarea.scrollTop($textarea[0].scrollHeight);` to `$textarea.scrollTop(0);` to scroll to the top of `textarea`.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
    var $textarea = $('#update');
    $textarea.scrollTop(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Scroll</button>
<textarea Name="update" Id="update" cols="50" rows="25"></textarea>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I tested it and it does what the question asked

Comment: It works! How can I use both scroll to last and top function in this?

Comment: $textarea.scrollTop($textarea[0].scrollHeight); will take you to the bottom. You will probably need two buttons (depends on requirements) One that will take you to the top and other on click will take you to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Try this javascript code. Set the top and left to 0 and scrolls the textarea to top from bottom.

```js
function scrolltop() {
  var scr_top = document.getElementById("update");
  scr_top.scrollLeft = 0;
  scr_top.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="scrolltop()">Scroll</button>
  <textarea name="update" id="update" cols="50" rows="25"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete code.

On button click, The  content would navigate to bottom and/or top of the content of the tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="last">Scroll to bottom</button>
<textarea Name="update" Id="update" cols="50" rows="25"></textarea>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#last").on("click", function() {
    var $textarea = $('#update');
    $textarea.scrollTop($textarea[0].scrollHeight);
  });
});
</script>

<button id="first">Move to Top</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first").on("click", function() {
    var $textarea = $('#update');
    $textarea.scrollTop(0);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

1. `document.ready` should be checked on the outer scope, before any usage of JQuery.
2. for scrolling up to element top, scroll value should be 0

Hence:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        var $textarea = $('#update');
        $textarea.scrollTop(0);
    });
  });
```